# Ordered double linked list

Tags: c++, list, struct

I am trying to order a list of records by their lastname field which is type char array, i'm using the strcmp() function in my algorithm and I cannot sort out where it's going wrong.. the function's add to front and add to back feature work ok, it's just the add to middle, i get output like

Enter order 0 - Ascending, 1 - Descending: 0
2
5
3
4
6

If anybody here can see the problem give me a shout!

Main.cpp (basically just the menu)

Comment: Your title is C, but code is C++

Comment: Could you at least narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Not everything that uses `cout` is really C++.

Comment: I suggest you use `std::list` and `std::sort`.  You would have finished your task by now.

Comment: Do you really **need** all those statics?  Can they be replaced by local variables?

Comment: The "add to middle" code isn't adding to the middle of the list properly. the list is meant to be ordered

Comment: On which line did the debugger report the issue?

Comment: @Ktmock13: I've removed your shotgun tags, try to keep your tags on topic.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to update s2 and s3 in the while loop that seeks through the list (s1 doesn't change as far as I can see).

Moving

```
while(current!=last && x!=1)
{
```

up by two or three lines might do the trick.

You should also check whether the if-block after the loop is necessary.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179996/how-should-i-allocate-memory-for-c-string-char-array?answertab=votes#tab-top) you suggestion was helpful :)