# How to return char/string from sub function to main function without pointer?

Tags: c++

Hello I'm still a beginner in c++ or coding in general.So my lecturer didn't teach us about pointer.

so i search the internet and you would need to use `char*` to call it.since I cannot use `char*` I only can use `char name();`

```
char* name();// example for char* I want without *
char*name(){
        char name[50];
        cout<<"name:";
        cin.getline(name,50);

        return name;
}

int main(){
      char staff[50];
      strcpy(staff,name());
      cout<<"name:"<<staff;

     return 0;
     }
```

How to return the `name`  to the main function without using `char*` and use  `char();` (note that I could use reference but I don't know if char could use for it too).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably be using `std::string`.

Comment: Never name a variable the same as the function you are in. This is confusing to the reader.

Comment: `char*name(){` when the `name` function ends your local variable `name` no longer exists so the pointer that you return is not valid. Google for dangling pointer.

Comment: "*my project needs to use function without parameter*" Can you explain why this is? It's very hard to solve a problem when you don't understand what the actual problem is and only know someone's suggestion for how to solve it.

Comment: `char*` is a pointer not an array. you cannot return c-arrays from functions

Comment: if you drop `char*` and use `std::string` your code is as simple as `std::cin >> name;`. Is it a requirement to write a function? I agree with DavidSchwartz, it is not clear what is part of your solution and what is a real requirement. It seems you already realized that using `char*` isnt the solution, are you allowed to use `std::string` ?

Comment: No I wasn't allowed to use std:: string

Comment: @david schwartz it is just the requirement for my project. I know you can return a single char without using pointer but when dealing with a string, it becomes messy..

Comment: @MuhdAlifHaiqalHazizi What, precisely, is the requirement? Is it that the function not take any parameters? Not return any parameters? Or what exactly?

Comment: It is function that takes no parameters and it return it own parameter to the main function.

Comment: Are you allowed to create a class that you can return? Otherwise, the assignment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: what must the ``name`` function even do? Because with the information there is now I only can come up with the fact that this is really stupid

Answer (score 3):

The code you are looking for looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string name();

int main() {
  std::string staff;
  staff = name();
  std::cout << "name:" << staff << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

std::string name() {
  std::string aName;
  std::cout << "name: ";

  std::getline(std::cin, aName);
  return aName;
}
```

[`std::string`](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rstr-string) is a class which manages the allocation, access and deallocation of the buffer wherein the character data is stored. Internally it has a pointer to the data. This object can easily be value copied and even moved if you want the pointed data to remain in place.

These move semantics would look like: `staff = std::move(name());` This will only copy the pointer to the data and not the data pointed to by the pointer.

[Individual pointers should never be used to transfer ownership in C++.](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r3-a-raw-pointer-a-t-is-non-owning) `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` [should be used](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r20-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-represent-ownership).

If you really want to return the data using a raw pointer (which is a [**really bad idea**](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)) you will [have to use](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r10-avoid-malloc-and-free) `new` and `new[]` because this will allocate space on the free store which will remain usable when the function reaches the end of its scope. But it also makes the outer function responsible for the deallocation of the memory when the program ends with a call to `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: If you must use 'new', never forget to 'delete' when you're done with it.  Likewise, if you use 'new[]', you must use 'delete[]'.  MUST.

Comment: Yeah about the std:: string.. we can't use it.. can you show the really bad idea? Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @MuhdAlifHaiqalHazizi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179996/how-should-i-allocate-memory-for-c-string-char-array that could be a duplicate for this question but the person asking the question changed the question after the answer showed to use new.

Comment: The original code for that answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15179996/1

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not allowed to use `std::string`, and want to return by `char *` you may do something like this:

```
auto name() {
  char* p = new char[50]{};
  std::cin.getline(p, 50);
  return p;
}

int main() {
  auto n = name();
  std::printf("%s\n", n);
  delete[] n; // now you're responsible to free this
}
```